# Flash Builder iPhone app size

Tags: flex4, flash-builder4.5

I have a mobile Flex project which I am deploying to iPhone/iPod and Android. I'm having an issue getting my app under the 20 MB 3g size limit. I am including some images and a video which amount to 1.5 MB. The swf for the build is 2.8 MB and the resulting ipa is 9.7 MB with the app file being 22.4MB. The app store shows the final size as 21.1 MB, though I understand Apple needs to add additional things to the package is it really supposed to grow that significantly? What started as 3.3 MB has now grown to over 20 MB.

I've seen people say that all that matters is the ipa size, which is obviously not what is happening here. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ipa is a compressed format and the download size is uncompressed. In other words, users don't download the ipa file in it's compressed state to their iPhone/iPod/iPad. If you rename ipa to zip and unzip it this is what you want to try and get below 20 mb. I'm having the exact same problem as you since the AIR overhead eats up a significant part of that 20 mb. Hope this explanation helps - good luck!
-Tom